# Running piped script with Java

Tags: java, shell, process

I'm trying to do this

```
echo "ls|head -3"|/bin/sh
```

in Java.

The important point is that I want to create the script string on the fly and run a shell process with that script and catch the script stdout.

The above code don't work and hangs, probably on the input stream.

```
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh");

        final OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();
        final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        final String cmd = "ls|head -3";

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    out.write(cmd.getBytes());
                    out.flush();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        }).start();


        final List list = new ArrayList();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String line;
                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        list.add(line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        }).start();

        System.err.println("running ...");
        p.waitFor();

        System.err.println(list);

    }
```

Comment: Instead of read use available > 0 in your test read condition

Answer (score 0):

Your output stream needs to be closed before there will be data on the input stream.  Closing the output stream confirms to the process that no further input will come to it.  Only then will it begin processing and outputting to your input stream.

Try adding the following code in your first Thread, after your call to "flush":

```
out.close();
```